# get x elements from center of vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

How do I create a function (e.g. here, an anonymous one but I don't mind any) to get `x` elements from `vec` that are most centered (i.e. around the median)? In essence I want a function with same syntax as Matlab's `randsample(n,k)`, but for non-random, with elements spanning around the center.

```
cntr=@(vec,x) vec(round(end*.5)+(-floor(x/2):floor(x/2))); %this function in question
cntr(1:10,3) % outputs 3 values around median 5.5 => [4 5 6];
cntr(1:11,5) % outputs => [4 5 6 7 8]
```

Note that `vec` is always sorted.

One part that I struggle with is not to output more than the limits of `vec`. For example, `cntr(1:10, 10)` should not throw an error.

edit: sorry to answer-ers for many updates of question

Comment: the text, will update examples. Basically the same functionality as randsample, but for center of vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a one-line anonymous function, but you can do this pretty simply with a couple calls to [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
function vec = cntr(vec, x)
  [~, index] = sort(abs(vec-median(vec)));
  vec = vec(sort(index(1:min(x, end))));
end
```

The upside: it will still return the same set of values even if `vec` isn't sorted. Some examples:

```
>> cntr(1:10, 3)

ans =
     4     5     6

>> cntr(1:11, 5)

ans =
     4     5     6     7     8

>> cntr(1:10, 10)  % No indexing errors

ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> cntr([3 10 2 4 1 6 5 8 11 7 9], 5)  % Unsorted version of example 2

ans =

     4     6     5     8     7  % Same values, in their original order in vec
```

### OLD ANSWER

*NOTE: This applied to an earlier version of the question where a range of `x` values below and `x` values above the median were desired as output. Leaving it for posterity...*

I broke it down into these steps (starting with a sorted `vec`):

1. Find the values in `vec` less than the median, get the last `x` indices of these, then take the first (smallest) of them. This is the starting index.
2. Find the values in `vec` greater than the median, get the first `x` indices of these, then take the last (largest) of them. This is the ending index.
3. Use the starting and ending indices to select the center portion of `vec`.

Here's the implementation of the above, using the functions [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html), and [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html):

```
cntr = @(vec, x) vec(min(find(vec < median(vec), x, 'last')):max(find(vec > median(vec), x)));
```

And a few tests:

```
>> cntr(1:10, 3)  % 3 above and 3 below 5.5

ans =
     3     4     5     6     7     8

>> cntr(1:11, 5)  % 5 above and 5 below 6 (i.e. all of vec)

ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11

>> cntr(1:10, 10)  % 10 above and 10 below 5.5 (i.e. all of vec, no indexing errors)

ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Answer (score 3):

`median` requires sorting the array elements. Might as well sort manually, and pick out the middle block (*edit: OP's comment indicates elements are already sorted, more justification for keeping it simple*):

```matlab
function data = cntr(data,x)
x = min(x,numel(data)); % don't pick more elements than exist
data = sort(data);
start = floor((numel(data)-x)/2) + 1;
data = data(start:start+x-1);
```

You could stick this into a single-line anonymous function with some tricks, but that just makes the code ugly. :)

Note that in the case of an uneven division (when we don't leave an even number of elements out), here we prioritize an element on the left. Here is what I mean:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   => 11 elements, x=4
      \_____/
picking these 4 values
```

This choice could be made more complex, for example shifting the interval left or right depending on which of those values is closest to the mean.

---

Given `data` (i.e. `vec`) is already sorted, the indexing operation can be kept to a single line:

```matlab
cntr = @(data,x) data( floor((numel(data)-x)/2) + (1:x) );
```

The thing that is missing in that line is `x = min(x,numel(data))`, which we need to add twice becuase we can't change a variable in an anonymous function:

```matlab
cntr = @(data,x) data( floor((numel(data)-min(x,numel(data)))/2) + (1:min(x,numel(data))) );
```

This we can simplify to:

```matlab
cntr = @(data,x) data( floor(max(numel(data)-x,0)/2) + (1:min(x,numel(data))) );
```

Comment: you helped me understand and refine the question, thanks for the elaborations